# Is there any way I can use switch statement inside a container in assigning colors to that container from a list of colors

Tags: flutter, dart

Like I want to assign same color to container after each interval. Like in this picture the first twelve colors will inherit their color from first element of the second column and the next twelve will inherit from the second one in the second column and so on:

[image]

How can I achieve this type of functionality in my flutter code.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage(
      {Key? key,})
      : super(key: key);



  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Color> manyColors = [
      Colors.blue,
      Colors.red,
      Colors.yellow,
      Colors.amber,
      Colors.purple,
      Colors.pink,
      Colors.black,
      Colors.blueAccent,
      Colors.cyan,
      Colors.lightBlue,
      Colors.lime,
      Colors.orangeAccent,

    ];

    List<Widget> myRowChildren = [];
    var myTubeChildren;
    List<List<int>> numbers = [];
    List<int> columnNumbers = [];
    int z = 1;
    int numberOfTubes = 12;
    int fpt=12;

    List fiberList = new List<int>.generate(numberOfTubes*fpt, (i) => i + 1);
    List tubeList = new List<int>.generate(numberOfTubes, (i) => i + 1);

    myRowChildren = fiberList
        .map((index) => Container(
      width: 50,

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color:(index<=manyColors.length) ? manyColors[0%manyColors.length] : manyColors[1%manyColors.length],
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 1,
          )),
      child: Text(
        '$index ',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ))
        .toList();

    myTubeChildren = tubeList
        .map((index) => Container(
      width: 50,

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: manyColors[(index - 1) % manyColors.length],
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 1,
          )),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'T$index',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    ))
        .toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Asterisk test"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: myRowChildren,
            ),
            Column(
              children: myTubeChildren,
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Right now I am using ternary operator inside the color attribute it does the same thing but it only checks for two values which are not dynamic unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I was able to produce the wanted behaviour by using `ListView.builder()`

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Color> manyColors = [
      Colors.blue,
      Colors.red,
      Colors.yellow,
      Colors.amber,
      Colors.purple,
      Colors.pink,
      Colors.black,
      Colors.blueAccent,
      Colors.cyan,
      Colors.lightBlue,
      Colors.lime,
      Colors.orangeAccent,
    ];

    List<Widget> myRowChildren = [];
    var myTubeChildren;
    List<List<int>> numbers = [];
    List<int> columnNumbers = [];
    int z = 1;
    int numberOfTubes = 12;
    int fpt = 12;

    List fiberList = new List<int>.generate(numberOfTubes * fpt, (i) => i + 1);
    List tubeList = new List<int>.generate(numberOfTubes, (i) => i + 1);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Asterisk test"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: fiberList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: manyColors[(index / 12).floor().toInt()],
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 1,
                    )),
                child: Text(
                  '${index + 1} ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: manyColors[index % 12],
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 1,
                    )),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'T${index + 1}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is on point. Thank you. Can you tell me another thing. I want to map another set of columns like these to lets say 13th element of first column. How would I map the second listview so that it starts from the 13th element and goes down just like this one.

Comment: You dont need a second listview if you're trying to add a third column. Create the new list and then add a third container to the row in the itembuilder to add your third column.